# What setting on a thermomix would create a simmer?

Tags: simmer

Making marmalade in a thermomix and I need to simmer.  What setting should give me a simmer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer, I don't have thermomix)

[Simmering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simmering) is usually just below boiling temperature (100c), so I would set at 80c and see how it goes depending on the marmalade consistency.

Most recipe I've seen just say to simmer the marmelade; no set temperature.

I'd also look at the Thermomix user manual or user community to see if there are instructions or marmelade recipes